# Does an inherited function not count as an implementation?

Tags: c++

I have a function defined in a superclass, InteractorStyle. Then I have another class that requires that function to be implemented (pure virtual), PointSelector. Then a subclass of PointSelector, PointSelector2D, is instantiated. The compiler complains that I can't instantiate an abstract class because MyFunction() is not implemented. Why doesn't the function that gets inherited from InteractorStyle count as this implementation?

```
#include <iostream>

// I can't change these:
class InteractorStyle
{
  void MyFunction(){}
};

class PointSelector
{
  virtual void MyFunction() = 0;
};

class PointSelector2D : public InteractorStyle, public PointSelector
{

};


int main()
{
  PointSelector2D a;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's because `InteractorStyle` is not a subclass of `PointSelector`, so its `MyFunction` does not count as an override of `PointSelector`'s pure virtual `MyFunction`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because with multiple inheritance, you have now inherited two unrelated functions, one from each base class.  They just so happen to have the same name as each other (in fact, they don't; one is called `InteractorStyle::MyFunction`, the other is called `PointSelector::MyFunction`).

But one does not override the other (at least, not in the sense that you are hoping for).

Comment: +1 - it helps to consider what happens when you access an object through a `InteractorStyle&` and through a `PointSelector&`: in the former case, the non-virtual function gets called, in the latter you're calling the most derived implementation of the virtual.

Answer (score 3):

In the code that you present `InteractorStyle::MyFunction` is non-virtual. Thus it cannot override or "implement" any virtual function.

But even if you add a `virtual` keyword there, `InteractorStyle::MyFunction` still won't serve as implementation of `PointSelector::MyFunction` in your derived class `PointSelector2D`.

In order to serve as implementation, `InteractorStyle::MyFunction` must be defined in a class that is derived from `PointSelector`. But if you simply do that, let `InteractorStyle` inherit from `PointSelector`, then with the rest of the code unchanged it *still* won’t be an implementation down in `PointSelector2D`. And it will be worse, it will introduce ambiguity!

Why? Because `PointSelector2D` then contains two `PointSelector` base class sub-objects, one from `InteractorStyle` (where you added the inheritance), and one from its direct inheritance from `PointSelector`.

So, if you need to keep the code such that `InteractorStyle2D` inherits explicitly from `PointSelector`, *and* you want to bring in implementation via inheritance, sort of like in Java, then …

the solution is to recognize that `PointSelector` is effectively an **interface** class, and to inherit *virtually* from it, which ensures that there’s only one base class sub-object:

```
// This class defines an "interface".
class PointSelector
{
public:
    virtual void myFunction() = 0;
};

// Derived virtually from the interface
class InteractorStyle
    : virtual public PointSelector
{
public:
    void myFunction(){}
};

class PointSelector2D
    : public virtual PointSelector
    , public InteractorStyle
{};


int main()
{
  PointSelector2D a;        // Ooh, it works! :-)
  a.myFunction();           // Yay! No ambiguity!
}
```

But what about the ambiguity for lookup? Well, the virtual derivation fixed that too, because it brings in a special rule called **dominance**, where essentially the compiler recognized that due to the virtual derivation, `PointSelector::myFunction` and `InteractorStyle::myFunction` must be the same, and that the former is declaration while the latter in a derived class must be an implementation. It's a bit difficult to explain clearly since I’ve never found the standard’s clauses about it, but at least in C++0x N3290 you now find “dominance” in the index, referring to the non-normative dominance example in §10.2/10 and §10.2/11.

But, anyway, this is how to do implementation inheritance Java-style in C++.

Cheers & hth.,